# tf.custom_gradient with multiple inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow

[`tf.custom_gradient`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient) accepts only one Tensor `x`, what if this op needs more than one inputs?

For example, to define the gradient of Softmax which needs input `x` and `label`?

### Update

Thanks for the suggestion from @AllenLavoie, I use a Python list as input.

```
def self_define_op_multiple_inputs():
    @tf.custom_gradient
    def loss_func(input_):
        x = input_[0]
        label = input_[2]

        def grad(dy):
            return [dy, dy]

        return x - label, grad

    x = tf.range(10, dtype=tf.float32)
    y = tf.range(10, dtype=tf.int32)

    loss = loss_func([x, y])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    self_define_op_multiple_inputs()
```

It seems that it will convert the Python `list` to a `Tensor`. The snippet above will raise a `TypeError`:

`TypeError: Cannot convert a list containing a tensor of dtype <dtype: 'int32'> to <dtype: 'float32'> (Tensor is: <tf.Tensor 'range_1:0' shape=(10,) dtype=int32>)`

How to fix it?

Comment: The documentation says `x` and `y` can both either be Tensors or sequences of Tensors. Did this not work for you?

Comment: @AllenLavoie Actually this is exactly what confused me. I don't understand what's *sequences* of Tensors, does it mean a Python `list` of Tensor?

Comment: My interpretation is Python `list` (or `tuple`, etc.). So `len(x)` is the number of inputs to the operation, `len(y)` is the number of outputs.  Then the gradient function takes `len(y)` `Tensor` argument and returns `len(x)` `Tensor`s.

Comment: @AllenLavoie I tried to use `list` but it seems like a `list` will be converted as a `Tensor`, which will cause an error if there are multiple inputs with different type and matched shape. The question has been updated.

Comment: I see, so the documentation is off. Rather than taking a list of `N` arguments, the function takes `N` positional arguments. `def loss_func(x, label):` works for me (but I didn't test very deeply). Could you file a bug?

Comment: @AllenLavoie I created an issue on [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21756)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem yesterday and found this post, and I believe I know what you are running into. Problem is that while using @tf.custom_gradient, the function that it decorates can have multiple inputs (instead of a list of tensors). Look at the following code(note that it's just a test code with no actual meaning):

```
@tf.custom_gradient
def loop1(x,a):
    def grad(dy):
        return dy*3,dy*2
    n = tf.multiply(x,a)
    return n,grad
```

By using two inputs x and a, you have to return two gradients respectively in the grad function. dy*3 corresponds to the gradient of x and dy*2 corresponds to the gradient of a.

I think in this function the documents make people very confusing, but you can still use multiple inputs, just make sure that you also have the same number of gradients, or else you will run into errors.

Comment: Can we return `None` as gradients for unused terms ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need something like this a tf Graph input:+
n_input is the input number

```
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None])
```

Does this answer your question ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it seems that you didn't understand what I am talking about. `tf.custom_gradient` is not a computational graph. You can read docs for more details.